# Cognos Query to calculate a run date

Tags: cognos

So in my Cognos report I have a column 'Last Separation Date'.  I want run a query on that column to calculate to all persons currently employed or separated from employment within the last two years.  However, this date query should auto run to the day I'm running the report.  For example.  I run the report today 2/22/2020 and view data for the last two year till 2/22/2018.  I login few days later to view the report on 3/1/2020.  The report should pull data from 3/1/2018.

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter with the between function using current date and some expression which determines a date two years in the past.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_mdlg.doc/c_sql99_current_date.html#sql99_current_date

_add_years or _add_days  might be handy as they take negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answers suggestions, your detail filter would be similar to 
[Last Separation Date] between current_date and _add_years(current_date,-2)